# Dafny can't tell that a right shift decreases a bv64

Tags: dafny

Consider this lemma:

```
lemma Shift(input: bv64)
    decreases input
{
    Shift(input >> 7);
}
```

Dafny says `decreases clause might not decrease`... but this is a really simple expression. Surely it can figure out that `input >> 7` must be less than `input`?

Answer (score 2):

Ah actually it is technically correct because `0 >> 7` is not less then 0. If I change it to this it is happy:

```
lemma Shift(input: bv64)
    decreases input
{
    if (input > 0) {
        Shift(input >> 7);
    }
}
```